# psql: Sequential scan used instead of index when searching on tsvector tokens

Tags: postgresql

There seems to be a threshold crossed where searching on enough keywords, the query starts using a sequential scan instead of the index.

Is there any way around this, or a way to speed this up?

This query:

```sql
SELECT ID 
FROM people 
WHERE 
((  title_tokens 
    @@ 
    websearch_to_tsquery(
        'simple', 
        'sales or commercial')
))
```

Appears to use the index:

```
  [["Bitmap Heap Scan on people  (cost=1546.20..325792.66 rows=164929 width=8)"],
   ["  Recheck Cond: (title_tokens @@ '''sales'' | ''commercial'''::tsquery)"],
   ["  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_people_on_title_tokens  (cost=0.00..1504.97 rows=164929 width=0)"],
   ["        Index Cond: (title_tokens @@ '''sales'' | ''commercial'''::tsquery)"],
   ["JIT:"],
   ["  Functions: 4"],
   ["  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true"]]>
```

However, this query:

```sql
SELECT ID 
FROM people 
WHERE 
((  title_tokens 
    @@ 
    websearch_to_tsquery(
        'simple', 
        'sales or commercial or growth or demand or gen or gtm or cmo or chief or founder or ceo or gm')
))
```

Uses a sequential scan:

```
  [["Seq Scan on people  (cost=0.00..402871.58 rows=392222 width=8)"],
   ["  Filter: (title_tokens @@ '''sales'' | ''commercial'' | ''growth'' | ''demand'' | ''gen'' | ''gtm'' | ''cmo'' | ''chief'' | ''founder'' | ''ceo'' | ''gm'''::tsquery)"],
   ["JIT:"],
   ["  Functions: 4"],
   ["  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true"]]>
```

Comment: Well at some point, the seq scan actually will be faster.  Are you sure it is not making the right decision here?  For testing purposes, you can force it to use the index by doing `set enable_seqscan=off`

Comment: It could be making the right decision - I just didn't know if they were other ways to speed this up.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.